# Can't use JS in RoR like action

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make some web in rails.
And I want to make "like button" as like Facebook.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :care_articles do
resources :care_articles do
  member do
    post "like",    to:    "care_articles#like"
  end
end
```

**care_articles_controller.rb**

```
def like
  like = CaLike.find_by(user_id: current_user.id, care_article_id: params[:care_article_id])
  if like == nil
    like = CaLike.create(user_id: current_user.id,  care_article_id: params[:care_article_id])
    like.save   
  else
    like.destroy
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

in my **index.html.erb**  it has partial **_care_article.html.erb**

```
        ...
        <div class="ca_likes">
          <%= care_article.ca_likes.size %> 
          <%= render 'care_articles/buttons', care_article: care_article %>  
        </div> 
        ...
```

**_buttons.html.erb**

```
<% if current_user.ca_likes.where(care_article_id: care_article).present? %>
  <%= link_to icon('suit-heart-fill'), like_care_article_path(care_article), 
              id: "js-like-#{care_article.id}", remote: true, method: :post %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to icon('suit-heart'), like_care_article_path(care_article), 
            id: "js-like-#{care_article.id}", remote: true, method: :post %> 
<% end %>
```

**like.js.erb**

```
$('#js-like-<%= @care_article.id %>').replaceWith("<%= j (render partial: 'care_articles/button', locals: {care_article: @care_article}) %>");
```

in my CaLike model
CaLike.rb

> class CaLike < ApplicationRecord
> belongs_to :care_article
> belongs_to :user
> end

When I click the icon, nothing happened.
ㅡ
error appears.

POST http://co-kkirricare-ilipe.run.goorm.io/care_articles/4/like 500 (Internal Server Error)

ㅡ
and my server response

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial care_articles/_button with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handl
ers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
```

ㅡ
and there is no CaLike.save data at all.

What should I do for it to use js... please help me. I spend heavy times in here...

Comment: In your `like.js.erb` file you are rendering partial `care_articles/button` but your partial is named `_buttons.html.erb` - it is in plural, but in js.erb file you have it in singular. It should be `care_articles/buttons` (`s` at the end was missing). What is the CaLike model looks like? Btw. you are using `CaLike.create` which will save data to database directly, `like.save` call has nothing left to save.

Comment: Yeah, @edariedl is correct. `CaLike.create` is the same as `like = CaLike.new` and `like.save`.

Comment: @edariedl  thanks your answer. I changed my partial in like.js.erb as you mentioned. So there is no error. But I dont have any CaLike saved data when I click the 'suit-heat' icon. And there was no change in icon.."

class CaLike < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :care_article
  belongs_to :user
end

merry x-mas!!

Comment: @alex thanks!! I deleted like.save but I cant save any calike saving data ㅠ happy x-mas!

Comment: @kerbong Can you show us how `CaLike` looks like. Maybe there is some validation error or something like that. I would probably use `CaLike.create!(...)` - add exclamation mark `!` behind create, it should raise an exception if saving `CaLike` fails and tell you what could be wrong.

Comment: @edariedl I added CaLike model. and i added exclamation mark ! right after create. Adn also added validation code 

`class CaLike < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :care_article
  belongs_to :user
 
  validates :care_article_id, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end`


and my server tell...

 
`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Care article must exist, Care article can't be blank):

app/controllers/care_articles_controller.rb:10:in `like'`

so...what should I do now??

Comment: @kerbong Oh I see now, you are using `params[:care_article_id]` in your controller but it should be only `params[:id]` based on defined routes and the way path is created in `_buttons.html.erb`

Comment: @edariedl  WOW.....so much thanks. I got a js actions now!!!! Happy new year!